# Primefaces Calendar Date Selection

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

How can I trigger Ajax date select event in Primefaces Calender as soon as page loads?

When the page loads, Primefaces Calendar will be set as today's date as default date. I want to make sure that this date is sent to server side code when the page is loaded. Think about the scenario where the client's browser has different date than server's date. In this case, I want to make sure that client's side date is sent to server (JSF backing bean) when page is loaded by user.

Thanks

Comment: If you sole functional requirement is to figure the client's current date/time, is it really necessary to let it take place via PF calendar? Can't you just use plain JS with little help of PF remote command? What exactly is it, the problem you're trying to solve after all?

Comment: @BalusC 
I have a page that has Calendar component. The user can select a date on calendar and data for that date is loaded and rendered on the same page via Ajax. Everything is working fine when user selects a date. But when the page is loaded, there is no select event happens on calendar. In jQuery calendar, after page load I can manually trigger `$(".ui-datepicker-current-day").trigger("click")` which will fire Ajax event with current date on server side component. I could not make that to work in PF Calendar. Primefaces RemoteCommand sounds like a good idea.

Thanks